# How to prevent iterating over duplicate array elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates, upcase

Is it possible to avoid messing with duplicate array elements when you're messing with the first one?

Consider the following:

```
def rot13(str)
    alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
  letters = str.split("").each{|x| x.downcase! }

  letters.map! do |let|
      alphabet[(alphabet.index(let) + 13) % alphabet.length]
  end

  #werd = letters.join("")
  letters.map.with_index do |char,index|
      str.each_char.with_index do |c,idx|
          if str[idx].upcase! == nil
              letters.at(idx).upcase!
          end
      end
  end
  #werd

  letters
end

rot13("ANdrea")
```

This is just a Ceaser Cypher fixed at 13 letters over. Straightforward until we hit the duplicate `"a"`s, which turns into duplicate `"n"`s after the code runs. As it is here, the `upcase!` loop upcases in `letters` everything that was at those indexes in the original string, and I only need those *indexes* to be capitalized. How do I isolate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way you could do this

```
def input(str)
  alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a

  str.chars.map do |let|
    next let unless alphabet.include?(let.downcase)
    ceaser_letter = alphabet[(alphabet.index(let.downcase) + 13) % alphabet.length]
    let == let.upcase ? ceaser_letter.upcase : ceaser_letter.downcase
  end
end

input('ANdrea') 
=> ["N", "A", "q", "e", "r", "n"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a little unclear. This is my solution from what I got from it.

```
def rot13(str)
  alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
  cap_alphabet = ("A".."Z").to_a
  letters = str.split("")

  letters.map! do |letter|
    if alphabet.include?(letter)
      # Change these for different scambling
      alphabet[(alphabet.index(letter) + 13) % alphabet.length]
    else
      cap_alphabet[(cap_alphabet.index(letter) + 13) % alphabet.length]
    end
  end
end

p rot13("Andrea")
```

This will return ["N", "A", "q", "e", "r", "n"]

Answer (score 0):

For this *particular* problem, something much simpler will do the trick:

```
def rot13(str)
  str.chars.map do |c|
    next c unless c =~ /[A-z]/
    ((c.ord % 32 + 13) % 26 + c.ord / 32 * 32).chr 
  end.join
end

rot13("It's PJSCopeland!")
#=> "Vg'f CWFPbcrynaq!"
```